# @ shows solution navigator instead of typing an @

Tags: visual-studio-2010, keyboard

I can't seem to find a question on this, but it might be because I'm unable to find a good way to search for it...

I recently updated my installation of Visual Studio 2010 Pro Power Tools, and now every time I type `@` in a code window, I get a search window of some sort opened instead of the @ symbol in my code. I can't find the key setting that triggers this, and it's beginning to be a real problem.

I'm on a Swedish keyboard, so to get @ I press <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd>. I've gone through all the settings under Tools/Options/Keyboard that starts with "View.", but found nothing.

**Can anybody help me delete this keyboard mapping?**

---

Update: I just realized that the key mapping <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd> is equivalent to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd>. But I still can't find what it's mapped to...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem in the comment thread on [the VS team blog post on the Solution Navigator](https://web.archive.org/web/20151201020846/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/visualstudio/archive/2010/07/20/solution-navigator-blog-post.aspx) - it turns out this problem is built-in into the extension, and they're working on fixing it for the next release. (Basically, they're binding stuff to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd> and <kbd>2</kbd>, but VS also takes the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd> equivalents, which then are interpreted as <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd>...)

For now, disabling Solution Navigator solves the problem (but, obviously, makes Solution Navigator unavailable...), but hopefully there will be a fix out pretty soon.